# MVC4 routing with hashtags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, hashtag

I would like to create a route in my MVC application that will allow using hashtags in urls. If I would go to `www.mydomain.com/#tag1` a specific controller for tag1 must take care of that request. If I would go to `www.mydomain.com/#tag2`, a different controller for tag2 must take care of that request.

Is this possible in MVC4?

Answer (score 0):

use www.mydomain.com/ht#hashtag || then have ht defined as a forwarding or delegating controller that finds the correct controller to invoke

Answer (score 0):

> Is this even possible in MVC ?

This is not an issue with MVC. URL fragments (URLs with a hashtag #) are left up to the author of the browser to interpret. Many browsers do not pass this information back to the server, so relying on them for routing is not reliable across browsers.

So, in short yes this is possible with MVC (by [customizing routing](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=970)), but unless you can limit the browsers that your clients use to those that pass the fragment information to the server side it isn't practical.

[RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4) section 4.1:

> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the
> identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from
> the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional
> reference information **to be interpreted by the user agent after the
> retrieval action has been successfully completed**.  As such, it is not
> part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.

(emphasis added)

Typically, the usage of URL fragments is limited to the client side because that is the only place that all major browsers support them.